# Odoo - Import Product Description of Other Language

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

On Odoo 12 instance, we have two languages configured - English and Arabic. Now, I want to import the product descriptions - for English and Arabic. What is the best suitable way for doing this? Can someone please suggest.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For translatable fields, the value you update on an XLS or CSV import depends on the language the user has selected when the import is done.

So the way to do it is:

1. Select language X on your user settings
2. Import the X language descriptions for your products

Repeat the above steps for every language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I am trying this way, only Product Name is getting updated in other language, whereas the HTML Fields like Description are getting updated for all languages. For ex. I have a site with English and Arabic. I am changing the admin preferences to Arabic and importing sheet with Product Name and Description. In this case, Name is updated fine for Arabic, but for Description, the Arabic content is updated for Arabic and English. So, the file that I upload, irrespective of language, same Description is getting applied for all languages. Is there any setting for this?

Comment: In Odoo base, `description` is a regular text field, and so are `description_*` fields for sale, purchase, etc. So is it a custom field? Is it translatable? If you defined or changed the field, edit the question and show us the code so we can help you.